# Store a set of numbers in mysql

Tags: mysql, database-design, set

I need to store a set of integers in MYSQL. The problem is as : I have an id(integer). Each id is mapped to  a set of numbers. The numbers in the set can have values from 1 - 160. So my table should be of structure {id,set}. Also each id'set can have different length (max 40 numbers). 
Eg:

```
id   set
1    {2 45 46 67 89 155}
2    {1, 11 12 34 56 67 68 79 80 134 145}
```

I have tried the SET datatype in MYSQL. I defined it as 
CREATE TABLE mytable ( id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY , mycol SET('1','2','3','4'...))
But the problem is the set allows to define only 64 elemnets.

Note: I need options other than creating a mapping table as :

```
id   setno
1     2
1     45
....... and so on
```

Can anyone suggest another way to store a set of numbers in MYSQL.

Comment: What are you trying to do , the scenario please?

Comment: The actual problem is that of android category - permissions mapping.Each category (pre-defined) has almost 30-40 standard permissions (out of 160).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create child table to hold the numbers, one per row:

```
create table set_number (
    set_id int,
    num int
);
```

Then insert your numbers. To get them as one [CSV](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) value, use [`group_concat()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat), something like:

```
select t.id, group_concat(s.num) set
from mytable t
join set_nimber s
    on t.set_id = s.set_id
group by t.id
```

Answer (score 0):

The table structure you described is the right way to do.

And its all in the way you present data, create a table where it maps ID into Sento

And ID is a primary key

So that you will have:

```
ID Sento
1 2
1 45
1 46
...
1 155
```

And then have an SQL that says:

```
SELECT ID, GROUP_CONCAT(Sento, SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM Table
GROUP BY ID
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes this is one of the options i plan to go with as mentioned in my question (mapping table). Yet i would like to explore other options of storing set of numbers in Mysql.

Comment: The alternative is to use a `text` field for Sento and store the data there as text, it is very inefficient

Comment: Yes that is very inefficient with 1 byte per character. Thank you for suggestions